# Call to printf doesn't show up in disassembly after a call to exit function

Tags: c, printf, call, exit, disassembly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     exit(0);
     printf("%s\n", "Nice");
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to disable whatever it is that doesn't generate the instruction for a call to printf if it is placed right after a call to exit.
I'm using
`gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4)` and no flags when compiling. I have tried using -O0, but there is no change in the disassembly.

```
   0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     mov    $0x0,%edi
   0x0000000000400536 <+9>:     callq  0x400430 <exit@plt>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a smart compiler. It knows anything after `exit` never runs so why generate instructions for it?

Comment: I am trying to disable branch prediction, or optimization or whatever this is, but it isn't working. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 to compile. The reason I want it to generate instructions for it is because I am trying to create a ctf challenge xD

Comment: Well then [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66206228/edit) your question to ask how to do what you want it to rather than ask why it is doing what it is. Also include what compiler you are using and the exact build command.

Comment: `exit` is declared with the `_Noreturn` keyword, so the compiler does not need to be all that smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exit()` is defined in `<stdlib.h>` as never returning to its caller:

```
_Noreturn void exit(int status);
```

The compiler takes advantage of this and does not generate code for statements that are never reached. If you pass `-Wall` to get more diagnostics, you will get a warning about this.